# Spring and Velocity - form handling

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, velocity

I googled it, but could not find completely full answer. How can I handle the form from Spring, if I use Velocity templates as View?
Assume I have the following form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="newThreadForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Author" id="author"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
    <!-- other fields... -->
</form>
```

And have a simple class:

```
public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String author;
    private String email;
    private String title;
    //other fields

    //getters and setters
}
```

How can I convert the data that user types in the form to Post object in my Controller method?

```
 @RequestMapping(value="path/to/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String newThread(Model model) {
     //what should be there?
     return "view-name"; 
 }
```

Do I need to create a new class, smth like `public class NewThreadForm`? Add BindingResult argument to the method? Or what should I do? Thanks for answers.

UPD: I wrote:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{board}/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String newThread(Model model, @PathVariable("board") String boardName, Post post, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("newThread()");
    Board board = new Board();
    board.setName(boardName);
    post.setBoard(board);
    post.setDeletePassword(DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(post.getDeletePassword().getBytes()));
    post.setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());
    Thread newThread = new Thread();
    newThread.setOpPost(post);
    threadDao.addThread(newThread);
    return "redirect:/" + boardName; 
}
```

But when I send the form data, Spring shows me 400 error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. First line `log.info("newThread()");` doesn't runs. What's wrong?

UPD2: it was cause of "id", not "name" attributes in form html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public String newThread(Post post, Model model) { ... }` should work.  You will get a populated `Post` instance inside the method that you can validate, persist, etc.

Comment: Spring will just create a Post object with filled fields? It will just look at the form fields and class fields and find pairs with the same names? Will it correctly handle checkbox form fields and boolean class fields?

Comment: I did like u adviced, there's another problem, see upd